# Is Bootstrap 3.3.7 safe and secured if "data-target" attribute is unused?

Tags: security, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, xss

There is a [security vulnerability](https://snyk.io/test/npm/bootstrap/3.3.7?tab=issues) regarding Bootstrap 3.3.7. It says that "Affected versions of this package are vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks via the data-target attribute." I am wondering if v3.3.7 is safe to use if the "data-target" attribute is not used.

Comment: As far as I know it will be fixed in 3.4, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25679#issuecomment-420199818 you can use 3.4-dev

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.

Comment: 3.4.0 is released
https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2018/12/13/bootstrap-3-4-0/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The so called '*vulnerability*' only occurs if the `data-target` value relies on data injected by something external (directly or indirectly) AND is shown on a page where other users than the attacker are affected.

In other words this is NOT an issue if all your `data-target` attributes are made of hardcoded html text. It is also generally not an issue if this page is only seen by the attacker (self-hack ...).

For example you could also say jQuery `.html()` is a vulnerability, which is a more obvious case, but still vulnerable to XSS if you are a total web beginner or just did not pay attention.

So in general, avoid injecting unescaped user data in third-party: popups, tool-tips, ... or anything where DOM is directly manipulated behind the scenes.

I personally do not consider this a big vulnerability, but it is nicer if a famous framework like **bootstrap** handles this case or explicitly names the method as unsafe to warn developers.

Chrome audit considers bootstrap 3.3.x a vulnerability ([via synk](https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:bootstrap?lh=3.3.5)):

> Includes front-end JavaScript libraries with known security vulnerabilities

- [Is Bootstrap 3.3.7 safe and secured if "data-target" attribute is unused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52388366/is-bootstrap-3-3-7-safe-and-secured-if-data-target-attribute-is-unused)
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14989841